# how to set drawable background of edit text programmatically

Tags: java, android

Hello every one I am new in the android studio I have a picture in my drawable folder and I want it to save the picture as a background of the edit text programmatically for this I write a code bellow but its not working and it showing a red line error

here is my code.

```
edit_text.setBackground(R.drawable.background1);
```

any idea for this how I will write it
please don't suggest me another post as I am new here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should retrieve the background drawable using `ContextCompat.getDrawable` method:

```
edit_text.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.background1));
```